# How can i call function with string value that equals to function name

Tags: python, function

I'm trying to call *myFunc()* but i want to use a string value that equals to *"myFunc"* instead of typing by hand while calling it.

Here is some example that im trying to do;

```py
a = "myFunc"

def myFunc():
   print("Bla bla")

a() ### How can i compile this code like its myFunc()
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, you can call it with eval like this:

```
a = "myFunc()" 

def myFunc(): 
print("Bla bla") 

eval(a)                                                                                                                                             
Bla bla
```

Does this help? Thanks! Eval is useful for calling functions in a list for example, you can iterate a list of functions like:

```
for item in functionlist:
  eval(item)
```

Answer (score 2):

In your example `myFunc` is a global variable, so:

```
globals()[a]()
```

If you look at the dict returned by `globals()` you'll see (among other items):

```
{'a': 'myFunc', 'myFunc': <function myFunc at 0x0119B618>}
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer. This can be usefull too in different situations.

Answer (score 0):

I can think of two ways you can do it:

Using global namespace

```
In [1]: def myfunc():
...:     print('Bla bla!') 
In [2]: a = 'myfunc'
In [3]: globals()[a]()
Bla bla!
```

Or using `eval`

```
In [4]: eval(a + '()')
Bla bla!
```